# How to separate introduction from main theme with Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm trying to reproduce a music sheet with Lilypond, and it has an introduction separate from the main theme, but still on the same "line / staff / group of staves", just like so :
[image]

And I don't know how to reproduce that. What command would help me in that case ?

My code so far :

```
%%%%%%%%%%
%% VERSION
%%%%%%%%%%

\version "2.20.0"


%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PIANO UP
%%%%%%%%%%%

mff = ^ \markup { \italic Introduction }

pianoUpper = \relative c' {
    \override DynamicLineSpanner.staff-padding = #3
    \override BreathingSign.text = \markup {
        \musicglyph #"scripts.caesura.straight"
    }

    \clef "treble"
    \key d \minor

    \time 4/4

    <f a>2 \mff \f <f c'> |
    <f bes d>1 |
    \> << {bes4( a)} \\ {d,2} >> <e g>2 |
    %   \once \override Hairpin.to-barline = ##f
    f \fermata \breathe \! \bar "||" <a f'> \f |
    <c e> <b d> |
    <c e> <a c> |
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PIANO LOW
%%%%%%%%%%%%

pianoLower = \relative c {
    \override BreathingSign.text = \markup {
        \musicglyph #"scripts.caesura.straight"
    }
    \clef "bass"
    \key d \minor

    f2 a |
    bes1 |
    g2 c, |
    f \fermata \breathe f |
    c g' |
    c, f |
}


%%%%%%%%
%% SCORE
%%%%%%%%


\score {
    <<
    \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "upper" \pianoUpper
    \new Staff = "lower" \pianoLower
    >>
    >>
}
```

produces :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick puts your introduction inside of a score inside of a markup inside of the pianoStaff instrumentName.

[image]

See the code here: [lilypond code of answer in lilybin.com](http://lilybin.com/9k52wg/1)

Comment: That's really cool ! A question, though. Is there a way of knowing the length of the introduction, in order to align with the rest of the sheet when indenting ? Especially since I'm trying to write a collection, and similar alignment would be neat within the different pieces.

Comment: @JambonSama I'm afraid for now there is none I am aware of. Thankfully it is a single value that you have to manually code though.